# How should I write an "archive page" or "category index" with html5?

Tags: html, seo

I have a link list, where every item is associated with a short description and some meta info such as pubdate, author etc. 
How should I markup this in html5?

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <section>    .... OR ARTICLE?
           <header>
               <h1>title</h1>
               pubdate, author, etc
           </header>
           shortdesc
        </section>
    </li>
    .... repeat
</ul>
```

Do you think it is a good idea to use sections/article?

Or are plain `<li>`s better?

Article or section?

IMPORTANT NOTE: every item does not contain full content (article), just a short description and the link to the page that actually contains the article.

I'm also interested in a SEO point-of-view!

Comment: `article` is better suited than `section`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `article` here as each item is a separate entity on its own and could be syndicated (e.g. in a RSS feed). I wrote a bit about this a while ago: [HTML5: Section or Article?](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2011/04/html5/html5-section-or-article).

You also don't really need to use a list here, as each `article` could be seen as a list item.

I would also suggest using the `time` element to enclose the published date of each entry.

As for SEO what I've suggested is fine, as is the example code that you've posted.